# Writing an ASP.NET Custom Storage Provider

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-identity, azure-sql-database, owin

I would like to create my own custom identity provider using SQL Server and the ASP.NET identity tables. The provider would be responsible for authenticating several websites. I found [this tutorial](https://www.eximiaco.tech/en/2019/07/27/writing-an-asp-net-core-identity-storage-provider-from-scratch-with-ravendb/) using a RavenDB database, but I am completely baffled that I cannot find any examples on how to write this in C# with SQL Server.

I have looked in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity), Plural Sight, Channel 9 and many articles, but no luck.

I would appreciate any suggestions, tutorial, videos, and/or documentation on how to create my custom provider.